# awk filtering 0/0 wrongly recognized as mathematical operation

Tags: pattern-matching, divide-by-zero

I am trying to use awk to write lines to another document that do not contain 0/0 in the 10th column. 0/0 in this case is not a mathematical operation. I did the character matching in several ways:

```
awk '{ if($1 ~ /^#/) { print $0 } else { if($10 ~ !/0/0/) { print $0 } } }' raw_results.vcf > no0-0_results.vcf

awk '{ if($1 ~ /^#/) { print $0 } else { if($10!='0/0') { print $0 } } }' raw_results.vcf > no0-0_final_results.vcf
```

however seems I did not get the syntax right with 0/0 part. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

### First Awk Command

In your first attempt, you are not quoting the `0/0` string, so `awk` attempts to interpret it. In addition, you aren't using the `!` negation correctly. I think you should use the `!~` operator (meaning, "does not match"), and use a double-quoted `"0/0"`:

```
awk '{ if($1 ~ /^#/) { print $0 } else { if($10 !~ "0/0") { print $0 } } }' raw_results.vcf > no0-0_results.vcf
```

### Second Awk Command

In your second attempt, you are using single quotes `'` to quote the whole program given to `awk`. But then within that program you attempt to use single quotes to quote the `0/0`. That doesn't work, you end up with the shell swallowing the quotes, and `awk` sees `0/0` directly.

I believe `awk` uses double-quotes for string constants, so you should change to `"0/0"`:

```
awk '{ if($1 ~ /^#/) { print $0 } else { if($10!="0/0") { print $0 } } }' raw_results.vcf > no0-0_final_results.vcf
```